# Content goes too up and down that it gets out of margin

Tags: html, css

The content looks aligned and centered when it's full screen but it's not too responsive because the top and the bottom of the content get lost and remain not visible when you are shortening the width of the screen.

I'm using [this](https://piper-paige-template.blogspot.com/) Blogger template. I already contacted the seller but she's not responding...

What changes can I do to prevent this?

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

```
#Image903 p.text-caption {
    margin: 0 0 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only will happen in `769px-814px` screen widths becase `#Image903 p.text-caption` has `margin-top: 40px;` set. So, you can add a padding top to handle that situation. To fix this, find `@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)` and just add `padding-top: 40px;` to it as below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)
#Image903 p.text-caption {
    margin-top: -40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without touching any position more than your theme currently does … Really a lot of absolute position use in a bad way for those days.

You could also change the overflow like this :

```
#Image903 .about-content {
    overflow: visible;
}
```